# How to return multiple columns as a JSON with other columns

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a database with next scheme, that uses postgressql and the postgis plugin:

```
table_id | id | mag | time | felt | tsunami | geom
```

I have a next SQL to select some rows and return those columns as a JSON:

```sql
SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(t) as properties 
FROM ( 
  SELECT id, mag, time, felt, tsunami FROM earthquakes
) t
```

I would like to create an SQL sentence that returns the table_id, properties and geom like:

```
SELECT table_id, properties, GeometryType(geom) 
from earthquakes
```

How can I return the table_id and geom with properties as a JSON?

Edit:

I've created this sql:

```
SELECT table_id, 
row_to_json((SELECT d FROM (SELECT id, mag, time, felt, tsunami ) d)) AS properties, 
GeometryType(geom) 
FROM earthquakes ORDER BY table_id ASC;
```

But when I do a request with postman, it returns this:

```
[
    {
        "table_id": 1,
        "properties": {
            "type": "json",
            "value": "{\"id\" : \"ak16994521\", \"mag\" : 2.3}"
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

How can I return the values as an object?

My expected result should be:

```
[
    {
        "table_id": 1,
        "properties": {"id" : "ak16994521", "mag" : 2.3}
    },
    ...
]
```

Java Method:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> readTable(String nameTable) {
    try {
        String SQL = "SELECT table_id, GeometryType(geom) FROM " + nameTable + " ORDER BY table_id ASC;";           
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL);
    } catch( BadSqlGrammarException error) {
        log.info("ERROR READING TABLE: " + nameTable);
        return null;
    }
}
```

whit this code returns this json:

```
 [
    {
        "table_id": 1,
        "geometrytype": "POINT"
    },
    {
        "table_id": 2,
        "geometrytype": "POINT"
    },
    ....
]
```

My expected result should be:

```
[
    {
        "table_id": 1,
        "properties": {"id" : "ak16994521", "mag" : 2.3, "time": 1507425650893, "felt": "null", "tsunami": 0 },
        "geometrytype": "POINT"
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: You are selecting just from earthquakes table, right?  What is your expected result?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to show my expected result

Comment: Seems like there are extra steps between the SQL query and the Postman request, are you working on a web application?

Comment: You appear to be encoding the result-set as json. So the json inside gets double-encoded as it were.

Comment: You can quite literately do anything you can imagine in JSON, why don't you use your imagination?

Comment: I'm using springboot where I call a controller method and returns a table as geojson

Comment: Have you tried to do ```select table_id, to_json(id, mag, time, felt, tsunami) properties, GeometryType(geom) from earthquakes order by table_id desc ``` ?

Comment: It'd be nice to see the Java code that fetches this information and prepares the reply

Comment: select table_id, to_json(id, mag, time, felt, tsunami) properties, GeometryType(geom) from earthquakes order by table_id desc this doesnt work because to_json not exists.

There is java code

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the whole conversion to JSON on the database?

```
SELECT json_agg(x) as json_values FROM (
  SELECT 
    table_id, 
    row_to_json((select d from (select id, mag, time, felt, tsunami) d)) as properties, 
    GeometryType(geom)
  FROM earthquakes 
  ORDER BY table_id ASC
) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this sql that creates a [geojson file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139752/creating-geojson-from-postgres), so when I call method returns perfect as string serialized.

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc) FROM ( 
 SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, 
  array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features FROM 
  (SELECT 'Feature' As type, 
    ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geom)::json As geometry, 
    row_to_json((SELECT l FROM (SELECT id, mag, time, felt, tsunami) As l )) As properties FROM terremotos As lg ) As f ) As fc;
```